# Adding "\usepackage{pdfpages}" generates ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx

Tags: graphics, packages, pdfpages, option-clash

I want to add at the end of the PDF some other PDF stuff, 2 documents with 4 and 2 pages. Therefore, I want to use `\usepackage{pdfpages}`. By inserting it in the document i get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx
```

By searching more details, I received the this info from from latexmkr:

```
The package graphicx has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [pdftex]
Adding the global options:
  ,pdftex
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

Im my code I use this frame for PDF picture stuff:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/pdf/}}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\usepackage{rotating}
```

Before inserting `\usepackage{pdfpages}` I haven't this kind of error. I know, that the error must be somewhere there, but I don't see it. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: Remove the option [pdftex]

Comment: Thanks! Seems working!
Question: I do some researche on this option, but i didn't get a better understanding of this option! Do you have some hints for me?
By the way: I hope, leaving away this option will not change my pictures and tables. Since know I didn't see any changes!

Comment: the option tells graphics to load the driver file `pdftex.def`, but nowadays this option is no longer needed as the loading is done automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information! So I can skip this driver load without any fear to break my whole dokument (pictures, tables, listings,...) right?

Comment: The rest of the information from was helpful! Thanks!